# Magento OAuthException: Invalid auth/bad request got a 400

Tags: rest, magento, oauth

I'm dying for this painfull issue with magento REST API. 
I can get the orders using REST API. Only when I try to create a product using POST method I get the following error.
My PHP code I tried with is given below.

```
function upload_to_store($id=null,$product_data=null)
{
    /**
     * Example of simple product POST using Admin account via Magento REST API. OAuth authorization is used
     */
    $callbackUrl = site_url() . "admin_products/upload_to_store/".$id;
    $temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl = "url" . urlencode($callbackUrl);
    $adminAuthorizationUrl = 'oauth_authorize';
    $accessTokenRequestUrl = 'token url';
    $apiUrl = 'api url';
    $consumerKey = '';
    $consumerSecret = '';
    session_start();
    if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && isset($_SESSION['state']) && $_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
        $_SESSION['state'] = 0;
    }
    try {
        $authType = ($_SESSION['state'] == 2) ? OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION : OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI;
        $oauthClient = new OAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, $authType);
        $oauthClient->enableDebug();
        if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && !$_SESSION['state']) {
            $requestToken = $oauthClient->getRequestToken($temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl);
            $_SESSION['secret'] = $requestToken['oauth_token_secret'];
            $_SESSION['state'] = 1;
            header('Location: ' . $adminAuthorizationUrl . '?oauth_token=' . $requestToken['oauth_token']);
            exit;
        } else if ($_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
            $oauthClient->setToken($_GET['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
            $accessToken = $oauthClient->getAccessToken($accessTokenRequestUrl);
            $_SESSION['state'] = 2;
            $_SESSION['token'] = $accessToken['oauth_token'];
            $_SESSION['secret'] = $accessToken['oauth_token_secret'];
            header('Location: ' . $callbackUrl);
            exit;
        } else {
            $oauthClient->setToken($_SESSION['token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
            $resourceUrl = "$apiUrl/products";
            $productData = json_encode(array(
                'type_id' => 'simple',
                'attribute_set_id' => 4,
                'sku' => $product_data['sku'],
                'weight' => $product_data['weight'],
                'status' => 1,
                'visibility' => 4,
                'name' => $product_data['name'],
                'description' => $product_data['description'],
                'short_description' => $product_data['short_description'],
                'price' => $product_data['price'],
                'tax_class_id' => 0,

            ));
            $oauthClient->disableRedirects();
            $headers = array('Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Content_Type' => 'application/json');
            $oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl, $productData, OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_POST, $headers);
            $response = $oauthClient->getLastResponseInfo();
            if (isset($response['url'])) {
                header('Location: ' . $response['url']);
            }
        }
        return true;
    } catch (OAuthException $e) {
        print_r($e);
    }}
```

I get this error:
`OAuthException: Invalid auth/bad request (got a 400, expected HTTP/1.1 20X or a redirect)`

How can I get rid of this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

did you ever get this solved?

For anyone running into the "Invalid auth/bad request (got a 400, expected HTTP/1.1 20X or a redirect)" error when doing a POST while a GET works fine, I have found that often it has to do with the (selected) REST attributes. Especially the 400 error.

In case of the POST above with the creation of a product, go to System -> Webservices -> REST attributes -> select the Administrator and make sure you have selected Catalog, Product and the below (write) possibilities. Press save and try again. Most of the time it will work fine after this if you have followed the documentation at http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/introduction.html